# gzip_static not working with nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx

I've got some compressed javascript files being served by nginx:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/shim.min.js.gz"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/zone.js.gz"></script>
```

but it appears that nginx is serving them as text/plain resulting in browser errors:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character   shim.min.js.gz:1
```

Looking at the headers, this is the response:

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Tue, 29 Nov 2016 18:03:01 GMT
ETag:W/"583ce194-68b3"
Last-Modified:Tue, 29 Nov 2016 02:01:56 GMT 
Server:nginx/1.10.2
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

gzip on;
gzip_static on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 5;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

        upstream node-app {
              server node1:3000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        }

        server {
              listen 80;
              index index.html
              error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
              access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
              root /var/www/public;

              location /api {
                proxy_pass http://node-app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
        }
}
```

I have gzip_static set to on but it doesn't appear to be working.  I am using the nginx docker image:

[>nginx:1.10.2-alpine](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/25a3fc7343c6916fce1fba32caa1e8de8409d79f/stable/alpine/Dockerfile)

This image is compiled with the gzip static module:

> --with-http_gzip_static_module

if I uncompress the javascripts and serve them uncompressed everything works fine.  Is there an issue with the mime types?  This works fine with:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/shim.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/zone.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

[Module ngx_http_gzip_static_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html):

> The ngx_http_gzip_static_module module allows sending **precompressed** files with the “.gz” filename extension instead of regular files.

[gzip_static](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html#gzip_static):

> Enables (“on”) or disables (“off”) **checking the existence** of precompressed files.

We have to have two files for supported compression clients (`/some/path/js/filename.js.gz`) and not supported (`/some/path/js/filename.js`).

> The files can be compressed using the gzip command, or any other compatible one.

Use in your html:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="/js/filename.js"></script>
```

and nginx will return to the client one of the files.

> It is recommended that the modification date and time of original and compressed files be the same.

Comment: Just a note to the "it's recommended". This is important. Because `gzip_static` just stopped working for me, and I realized it was because the modified date of the gzipped file was older than the non-gzipped file.

Comment: It works after ensure the timestamps are same (`touch test.js.*`), tested with two files, the test.js is just a HelloWorld, and the test.js.gz is real files. `curl  -H 'Accept-encoding: gzip' http://127.0.0.1:8056/js/test.js | gunzip
curl  http://127.0.0.1:8056/js/test.js`

Comment: Here is a way to test it. `curl -sI http://localhost/js/zone.js | grep ^Content-Length` to get uncompressed and `curl -sI -H 'Accept-encoding: gzip' http://localhost/js/zone.js | grep ^Content-Length` to get compressed data.